# eclipse code-recommenders with ADT

Tags: eclipse, plugins

i am using the ADT eclipse bundele form google, and i wone to intall code recommenders. Iam getting folowing error:
[image]

Did anyone succeeded installing this plugin on ADT ??

EDIT:

error message from Log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-03-09 10:32:16.468
!MESSAGE The 'org.eclipse.recommenders.completion.rcp.intelligent' proposal computer from the 'org.eclipse.recommenders.completion.rcp' plug-in did not complete normally. The extension has thrown a runtime exception.
!STACK 0
com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/java/LazyPackageCompletionProposal
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:967)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.injection.ExtensionFactory.loadExtension(ExtensionFactory.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.injection.ExtensionFactory.create(ExtensionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.createComputer(CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.getComputer(CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.sessionStarted(CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalCategory.sessionStarted(CompletionProposalCategory.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor$CompletionListener.assistSessionStarted(ContentAssistProcessor.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.fireSessionBeginEvent(ContentAssistant.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.prepareToShowCompletions(ContentAssistant.java:1696)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.access$6(ContentAssistant.java:1687)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant$2.run(ContentAssistant.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/java/LazyPackageCompletionProposal
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:662)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:356)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:151)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:585)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:543)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:529)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createParameterInjector(InjectorImpl.java:925)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getParametersInjectors(InjectorImpl.java:913)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:28)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.LazyPackageCompletionProposal
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 76 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The CNFE for LazyPackageCompletionProposal makes me think you are working with Eclipse 4.2? If so, consider upgrading to Eclipse Kepler 4.3. Code Recommenders 2.x is requires Kepler or later.

**Update 28.03.14:**

With the latest HEAD build, Code Recommenders now should work with Eclipse Juno 4.2 too. See
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431336 for details. This change will be part of Recommenders 2.1 which will officially be released with Eclipse Luna in June. Users get this from the head update site before that time. Check http://eclipse.org/recommenders/download/ for URLs.

Comment: i tryed with the Head version, and still the same error. Where can i finde the log file ?

Comment: In $workspace/.metadata/.log. You may also use the standard eclipse "Error Log" view to view its content.

Comment: Can't reproduce it with ADT. It works for me. If you want this to get fixed, please provide a stacktrace and a small sample code snippet (better a project) in bugzilla that allows to reproduce the error.

Comment: i edited my question, you can see the error message.